# Calclating the expected value of a exponential function

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I want to calculate the following integral:

$\int e^{a+bx} \ f(x)\ dx$

where $f(x)$ is the probability distribution of $X$. Is there a way to calculate this integral?

P.S. I don't want to use any specific density function, but rather I prefer to have an answer with $F(x)$ in it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By parts,

$$\int e^{a+bx} f(x)\,dx=\frac1be^{a+bx} f(x)-\int \frac1be^{a+bx} f'(x)\,dx.$$

Then by induction

$$\int e^{a+bx} f(x)\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k}}{b^{k+1}}e^{a+bx} f^{(k)}(x).$$

Or

$$\int e^{a+bx} f(x)\,dx=e^{a+bx}f^{(-1)}(x)-b\int e^{a+bx} f^{(-1)}(x)\,dx=\cdots\\
=e^{a+bx}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-b)^kf^{(-k-1)}(x)$$

provided the integral terms vanish in the limit. ($f^{(-k)}$ denotes the $k^{th}$ antiderivative.)

There is not much better that you can do.

Answer (score 0):

*We don't have a general closed form for all density functions*.

One may observe that considering *any* integrable function $g$ one may write
$$
\begin{align}
\int g(x)\:dx =\int e^{a+bx} \cdot e^{-a-bx} g(x)\:dx =\int e^{a+bx} \cdot f(x)\:dx
\end{align}
$$ with
$$
f(x):=e^{-a-bx} g(x).
$$ Thus having a *general* answer would mean that we have a *general closed form* of any antiderivative of $g$.

We do have a general closed form only for some families: $f(x):=cx^\alpha, f(x):=e^{\alpha x+\beta},\cdots$.